# Issue with webscraping through Python using beautiful soup

Tags: python-2.7, screen-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using below reffered code to scrape some item names from a site:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import csv
import urllib2
import sys
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.vodafone.de/privat/tarife/red-smartphone-tarife.html').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
soup.prettify()
items = soup.findAll('div', {"class": "txtBox"})
for item in items:
    print unicode(item.string).encode('utf8').strip()
```

**Problem:** When I am running this code, 18 "None" are getting printed instead names of 18 items.

Output snippet:

```
>>> 
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

Comment: The usual problems, eh? Did you look at `.stripped_strings` yet?

Comment: Did I mention already that the `soup.prettify()` method doesn't get you anything when used like that?

Comment: Yeah, .stripped_strings is working, but I had to use islice with it. Solution you just gave is more efficient as it is giving me only item names.

Comment: Yeah, you told my friend about soup.prettify. I decided to keep it because sometimes I just want to look at html structure by doing `print soup`

Comment: Use `print soup.prettify()` then. `.prettify()` *returns* the prettified string version of the tree, it does *not* alter `soup` itself.

Comment: downvote :(, but I knew that there must be something better than .stripped_strings + islice combo, that's why posted this question. Anyway, thanks for the help & Happy New Year in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really want to first take a close look at what you matched, these are more complex HTML structures, not just simple tags:

```
>>> items = soup.findAll('div', {"class": "txtBox"})
>>> items[0]
<div class="txtBox">
<h3>iPhone 5</h3>
<div class="pr-stars" style="background-position: 0px -108px">
</div>
<div class="details">
<select id="color">
<option value="4">Weiß</option>
<option selected="selected" value="5">Schwarz</option>
</select>
<select id="size">
<option value="4">16 GB</option>
<option selected="selected" value="5">32 GB</option>
<option value="6">64 GB</option>
</select>
<ul>
<li>8 Megapixel-Kamera</li><li>A6 Chip</li><li>112 Gramm leicht</li></ul>
<div class="price">
<span id="price"><br/>
</span></div>
</div>
<div class="button">
<a class="vfmodal-trigger" href="#">Details </a>
</div>
</div>
```

You probably want to take the value of the contained `<H3>` tag, if there is one:

```
for item in items:
    h3tag = item.find('h3')
    if h3tag is not None:
        print unicode(h3tag.string).encode('utf8').strip()
```

Comment: I tried this for prices also `for price in prices:
    spantag = price.find('span')
    if spantag is not None:
        print unicode(spantag.string).encode('utf8').strip()` but it is printing "None" only

Comment: Then `spantag.string` is empty. `.string` *only* gives you text directly contained in the tag. Look at what the tag contains and see if there is something you can use `find()` on, or use `.stripped_strings` again.

Comment: Yeah, I tried using .stripped_strings also and find('div') also but both methods yielded nothing, not even "None" values. Console printed nothing.